# Using reset.css looks different in different browsers

Tags: html, css, templates, reset, normalize

I've added `normalize.css` and `styles.css` to my template. Here's fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/767qc2j1/

But it looks different in Firefox and Chrome. Font-size looks different and the whole.

`<section id="articles">`
Because of font-size.

Please see it in full screen to see differences.
How to fix that? What kind of `reset.css` should I use? I also tried with this reset:

http://html5doctor.com/html-5-reset-stylesheet/

And it's still the same.

**Edited:** I just found that my another site looks different in chrome and Firefox. In Firefox everything looks like it's zoomed. What is this due to and how to fix it?

```css
/*! normalize.css v3.0.2 | MIT License | git.io/normalize */

/**
 * 1. Set default font family to sans-serif.
 * 2. Prevent iOS text size adjust after orientation change, without disabling
 *    user zoom.
 */

html {
    font-family: sans-serif; /* 1 */
    -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; /* 2 */
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; /* 2 */
}

/**
 * Remove default margin.
 */

body {
    margin: 0;
}

/* HTML5 display definitions
   ========================================================================== */

/**
 * Correct `block` display not defined for any HTML5 element in IE 8/9.
 * Correct `block` display not defined for `details` or `summary` in IE 10/11
 * and Firefox.
 * Correct `block` display not defined for `main` in IE 11.
 */

article,
aside,
details,
figcaption,
figure,
footer,
header,
hgroup,
main,
menu,
nav,
section,
summary {
    display: block;
}

/**
 * 1. Correct `inline-block` display not defined in IE 8/9.
 * 2. Normalize vertical alignment of `progress` in Chrome, Firefox, and Opera.
 */

audio,
canvas,
progress,
video {
    display: inline-block; /* 1 */
    vertical-align: baseline; /* 2 */
}

/**
 * Prevent modern browsers from displaying `audio` without controls.
 * Remove excess height in iOS 5 devices.
 */

audio:not([controls]) {
    display: none;
    height: 0;
}

/**
 * Address `[hidden]` styling not present in IE 8/9/10.
 * Hide the `template` element in IE 8/9/11, Safari, and Firefox < 22.
 */

[hidden],
template {
    display: none;
}

/* Links
   ========================================================================== */

/**
 * Remove the gray background color from active links in IE 10.
 */

a {
    background-color: transparent;
}

/**
 * Improve readability when focused and also mouse hovered in all browsers.
 */

a:active,
a:hover {
    outline: 0;
}

/* Text-level semantics
   ========================================================================== */

/**
 * Address styling not present in IE 8/9/10/11, Safari, and Chrome.
 */

abbr[title] {
    border-bottom: 1px dotted;
}

/**
 * Address style set to `bolder` in Firefox 4+, Safari, and Chrome.
 */

b,
strong {
    font-weight: bold;
}

/**
 * Address styling not present in Safari and Chrome.
 */

dfn {
    font-style: italic;
}

/**
 * Address variable `h1` font-size and margin within `section` and `article`
 * contexts in Firefox 4+, Safari, and Chrome.
 */

h1 {
    font-size: 2em;
    margin: 0.67em 0;
}

/**
 * Address styling not present in IE 8/9.
 */

mark {
    background: #ff0;
    color: #000;
}

/**
 * Address inconsistent and variable font size in all browsers.
 */

small {
    font-size: 80%;
}

/**
 * Prevent `sub` and `sup` affecting `line-height` in all browsers.
 */

sub,
sup {
    font-size: 75%;
    line-height: 0;
    position: relative;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}

sup {
    top: -0.5em;
}

sub {
    bottom: -0.25em;
}

/* Embedded content
   ========================================================================== */

/**
 * Remove border when inside `a` element in IE 8/9/10.
 */

img {
    border: 0;
}

/**
 * Correct overflow not hidden in IE 9/10/11.
 */

svg:not(:root) {
    overflow: hidden;
}

/* Grouping content
   ========================================================================== */

/**
 * Address margin not present in IE 8/9 and Safari.
 */

figure {
    margin: 1em 40px;
}

/**
 * Address differences between Firefox and other browsers.
 */

hr {
    -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
    box-sizing: content-box;
    height: 0;
}

/**
 * Contain overflow in all browsers.
 */

pre {
    overflow: auto;
}

/**
 * Address odd `em`-unit font size rendering in all browsers.
 */

code,
kbd,
pre,
samp {
    font-family: monospace, monospace;
    font-size: 1em;
}

/* Forms
   ========================================================================== */

/**
 * Known limitation: by default, Chrome and Safari on OS X allow very limited
 * styling of `select`, unless a `border` property is set.
 */

/**
 * 1. Correct color not being inherited.
 *    Known issue: affects color of disabled elements.
 * 2. Correct font properties not being inherited.
 * 3. Address margins set differently in Firefox 4+, Safari, and Chrome.
 */

button,
input,
optgroup,
select,
textarea {
    color: inherit; /* 1 */
    font: inherit; /* 2 */
    margin: 0; /* 3 */
}

/**
 * Address `overflow` set to `hidden` in IE 8/9/10/11.
 */

button {
    overflow: visible;
}

/**
 * Address inconsistent `text-transform` inheritance for `button` and `select`.
 * All other form control elements do not inherit `text-transform` values.
 * Correct `button` style inheritance in Firefox, IE 8/9/10/11, and Opera.
 * Correct `select` style inheritance in Firefox.
 */

button,
select {
    text-transform: none;
}

/**
 * 1. Avoid the WebKit bug in Android 4.0.* where (2) destroys native `audio`
 *    and `video` controls.
 * 2. Correct inability to style clickable `input` types in iOS.
 * 3. Improve usability and consistency of cursor style between image-type
 *    `input` and others.
 */

button,
html input[type="button"], /* 1 */
input[type="reset"],
input[type="submit"] {
    -webkit-appearance: button; /* 2 */
    cursor: pointer; /* 3 */
}

/**
 * Re-set default cursor for disabled elements.
 */

button[disabled],
html input[disabled] {
    cursor: default;
}

/**
 * Remove inner padding and border in Firefox 4+.
 */

button::-moz-focus-inner,
input::-moz-focus-inner {
    border: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

/**
 * Address Firefox 4+ setting `line-height` on `input` using `!important` in
 * the UA stylesheet.
 */

input {
    line-height: normal;
}

/**
 * It's recommended that you don't attempt to style these elements.
 * Firefox's implementation doesn't respect box-sizing, padding, or width.
 *
 * 1. Address box sizing set to `content-box` in IE 8/9/10.
 * 2. Remove excess padding in IE 8/9/10.
 */

input[type="checkbox"],
input[type="radio"] {
    box-sizing: border-box; /* 1 */
    padding: 0; /* 2 */
}

/**
 * Fix the cursor style for Chrome's increment/decrement buttons. For certain
 * `font-size` values of the `input`, it causes the cursor style of the
 * decrement button to change from `default` to `text`.
 */

input[type="number"]::-webkit-inner-spin-button,
input[type="number"]::-webkit-outer-spin-button {
    height: auto;
}

/**
 * 1. Address `appearance` set to `searchfield` in Safari and Chrome.
 * 2. Address `box-sizing` set to `border-box` in Safari and Chrome
 *    (include `-moz` to future-proof).
 */

input[type="search"] {
    -webkit-appearance: textfield; /* 1 */
    -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: content-box; /* 2 */
    box-sizing: content-box;
}

/**
 * Remove inner padding and search cancel button in Safari and Chrome on OS X.
 * Safari (but not Chrome) clips the cancel button when the search input has
 * padding (and `textfield` appearance).
 */

input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-cancel-button,
input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-decoration {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}

/**
 * Define consistent border, margin, and padding.
 */

fieldset {
    border: 1px solid #c0c0c0;
    margin: 0 2px;
    padding: 0.35em 0.625em 0.75em;
}

/**
 * 1. Correct `color` not being inherited in IE 8/9/10/11.
 * 2. Remove padding so people aren't caught out if they zero out fieldsets.
 */

legend {
    border: 0; /* 1 */
    padding: 0; /* 2 */
}

/**
 * Remove default vertical scrollbar in IE 8/9/10/11.
 */

textarea {
    overflow: auto;
}

/**
 * Don't inherit the `font-weight` (applied by a rule above).
 * NOTE: the default cannot safely be changed in Chrome and Safari on OS X.
 */

optgroup {
    font-weight: bold;
}

/* Tables
   ========================================================================== */

/**
 * Remove most spacing between table cells.
 */

table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}

td,
th {
    padding: 0;
}

/* styles.css */
*{
    /* Universal reset: */
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

header,footer,
article,section,
hgroup,nav,
figure{
    /* Giving a display value to the HTML5 rendered elements: */
    display:block;
}

body{
    /* Setting the default text color, size, page background and a font stack: */
    font-size:0.825em;
    color:#fcfcfc;
    background-color:#355664;
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

/* Hyperlink Styles: */

a, a:visited {
    color:#0196e3;
    text-decoration:none;
    outline:none;
}

a:hover{
    text-decoration:underline;
}

a img{
    border:none;
}

/* Headings: */

h1,h2,h3{
    font-family:"Myriad Pro","Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,Sans-Serif;
    text-shadow:0 1px 1px black;
}

h1{
    /* The logo text */
    font-size:3.5em;
    padding:0.5em 0 0;
    text-transform:uppercase;
}

h3{
    /* The slogan text */
    font-family:forte,"Myriad Pro","Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,Sans-Serif;
    font-size:2em;
    font-weight:normal;
    margin:0 0 1em;
}

h2{
    font-size:2.2em;
    font-weight:normal;
    letter-spacing:0.01em;
    text-transform:uppercase;
}

p{
    line-height:1.5em;
    padding-bottom:1em;
}

.line{
    /* The dividing line: */
    height:1px;
    background-color:#24404c;
    border-bottom:1px solid #416371;
    margin:1em 0;
    overflow:hidden;
}

article .line{
    /* The dividing line inside of the article is darker: */
    background-color:#15242a;
    border-bottom-color:#204656;
    margin:1.3em 0;
}

footer .line{
    margin:2em 0;
}

nav{
    background:url(img/gradient_light.jpg) repeat-x 50% 50% #f8f8f8;
    padding:0 5px;
    position:absolute;
    right:0;
    top:4em;

    border:1px solid #FCFCFC;

    -moz-box-shadow:0 1px 1px #333333;
    -webkit-box-shadow:0 1px 1px #333333;
    box-shadow:0 1px 1px #333333;
}

/* The clearfix hack to clear the floats: */

.clear:after{
    content: ".";
    display: block;
    height: 0;
    clear: both;
    visibility: hidden;
}

/* The navigation styling: */

nav ul li{
    display:inline;
}

nav ul li a,
nav ul li a:visited{
    color:#565656;
    display:block;
    float:left;
    font-size:1.25em;
    font-weight:bold;
    margin:5px 2px;
    padding:7px 10px 4px;
    text-shadow:0 1px 1px white;
    text-transform:uppercase;
}

nav ul li a:hover{
    text-decoration:none;
    background-color:#f0f0f0;
}

nav, article, nav ul li a,figure{
    /* Applying CSS3 rounded corners: */
    -moz-border-radius:10px;
    -webkit-border-radius:10px;
    border-radius:10px;
}

/* Article styles: */

#page{
    width:960px;
    margin:0 auto;
    position:relative;
}

article{
    background-color:#213E4A;
    margin:3em 0;
    padding:20px;

    text-shadow:0 2px 0 black;
}

figure{
    border:3px solid #142830;
    float:right;
    height:300px;
    margin-left:15px;
    overflow:hidden;
    width:500px;
}

figure:hover{
    -moz-box-shadow:0 0 2px #4D7788;
    -webkit-box-shadow:0 0 2px #4D7788;
    box-shadow:0 0 2px #4D7788;
}

figure img{
    margin-left:-60px;
}

/* Footer styling: */

footer{
    margin-bottom:30px;
    text-align:center;
    font-size:0.825em;
}

footer p{
    margin-bottom:-2.5em;
    position:relative;
}

footer a,footer a:visited{
    color:#cccccc;
    background-color:#213e4a;
    display:block;
    padding:2px 4px;
    z-index:100;
    position:relative;
}

footer a:hover{
    text-decoration:none;
    background-color:#142830;
}

footer a.by{
    float:left;

}

footer a.up{
    float:right;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html> <!-- The new doctype -->
<html>
<head>

    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

    <title>Coding A CSS3 &amp; HTML5 One Page Template | Tutorialzine demo</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="normalize.css" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css" />

    <!-- Internet Explorer HTML5 enabling code: -->

    <!--[if IE]>
    <!--<script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>-->

    <style type="text/css">
        /*.clear {*/
            /*zoom: 1;*/
            /*display: block;*/
        /*}*/
    </style>

    <![endif]-->

</head>

<body>

<section id="page"> <!-- Defining the #page section with the section tag -->

    <header> <!-- Defining the header section of the page with the appropriate tag -->

        <hgroup>
            <h1>Your Logo</h1>
            <h3>and a fancy slogan</h3>
        </hgroup>

        <nav class="clear"> <!-- The nav link semantically marks your main site navigation -->
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#article1">Photoshoot</a></li>
                <li><a href="#article2">Sweet Tabs</a></li>
                <li><a href="#article3">Navigation Menu</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>

    </header>

    <section id="articles"> <!-- A new section with the articles -->

        <!-- Article 1 start -->

        <div class="line"></div>  <!-- Dividing line -->

        <article id="article1"> <!-- The new article tag. The id is supplied so it can be scrolled into view. -->
            <h2>Photoshoot Effect</h2>

            <div class="line"></div>

            <div class="articleBody clear">

                <figure> <!-- The figure tag marks data (usually an image) that is part of the article -->
                    <a href="http://tutorialzine.com/2010/02/photo-shoot-css-jquery/"><img src="http://tutorialzine.com/img/featured/641.jpg" width="620" height="340" /></a>
                </figure>

                <p>In this tutorial, we are creating a photo shoot effect with our just-released PhotoShoot jQuery plug-in. With it you can convert a regular div on the page into a photo shooting stage simulating a camera-like feel.</p>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer luctus quam quis nibh fringilla sit amet consectetur lectus malesuada. Sed nec libero erat. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc mi nisi, rhoncus ut vestibulum ac, sollicitudin quis lorem. Duis felis dui, vulputate nec adipiscing nec, interdum vel tortor. Sed gravida, erat nec rutrum tincidunt, metus mauris imperdiet nunc, et elementum tortor nunc at eros. Donec malesuada congue molestie. Suspendisse potenti. Vestibulum cursus congue sem et feugiat. Morbi quis elit odio. </p>
            </div>
        </article>

        <!-- Article 1 end -->

        <!-- Article 2 start -->

        <div class="line"></div>

        <article id="article2">
            <h2>Sweet AJAX Tabs</h2>

            <div class="line"></div>

            <div class="articleBody clear">
                <figure>
                    <a href="http://tutorialzine.com/2010/01/sweet-tabs-jquery-ajax-css/"><img src="http://tutorialzine.com/img/featured/633.jpg" width="620" height="340" /></a>
                </figure>

                <p>Here we are making sweet AJAX-powered tabs with CSS3 and the newly released version 1.4 of jQuery.</p>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer luctus quam quis nibh fringilla sit amet consectetur lectus malesuada. Sed nec libero erat. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc mi nisi, rhoncus ut vestibulum ac, sollicitudin quis lorem. Duis felis dui, vulputate nec adipiscing nec, interdum vel tortor. Sed gravida, erat nec rutrum tincidunt, metus mauris imperdiet nunc, et elementum tortor nunc at eros. Donec malesuada congue molestie. Suspendisse potenti. Vestibulum cursus congue sem et feugiat. Morbi quis elit odio. </p>
            </div>
        </article>

        <!-- Article 2 end -->

        <!-- Article 3 start -->

        <div class="line"></div>

        <article id="article3">
            <h2>Halftone Navigation Menu</h2>

            <div class="line"></div>

            <div class="articleBody clear">
                <figure>
                    <a href="http://tutorialzine.com/2010/01/halftone-navigation-menu-jquery-css/"><img src="http://tutorialzine.com/img/featured/610.jpg" width="620" height="340" /></a>
                </figure>

                <p>Today we are making a CSS3 & jQuery halftone-style navigation menu, which will allow you to display animated halftone-style shapes in accordance with the navigation links, and will provide a simple editor for creating additional shapes as well.</p>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer luctus quam quis nibh fringilla sit amet consectetur lectus malesuada. Sed nec libero erat. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc mi nisi, rhoncus ut vestibulum ac, sollicitudin quis lorem. Duis felis dui, vulputate nec adipiscing nec, interdum vel tortor. Sed gravida, erat nec rutrum tincidunt, metus mauris imperdiet nunc, et elementum tortor nunc at eros. Donec malesuada congue molestie. Suspendisse potenti. Vestibulum cursus congue sem et feugiat. Morbi quis elit odio. </p>
            </div>
        </article>

        <!-- Article 3 end -->

    </section>

    <footer> <!-- Marking the footer section -->

        <div class="line"></div>

        <p>Copyright 2010 - YourSite.com</p> <!-- Change the copyright notice -->

        <a href="#" class="up">Go UP</a>
        <a href="http://tutorialzine.com/2010/02/html5-css3-website-template/" class="by">Template by Tutorialzine</a>

    </footer>

</section> <!-- Closing the #page section -->

<!-- JavaScript Includes -->

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.scrollTo-1.4.2/jquery.scrollTo-min.js"></script>
<script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: "I just found that my another site looks different in chrome and firefox. In firefox everything looks like it's zoomed. What is this due to and how to fix it?" — Have you configured your copy of Firefox to zoom the content?

Comment: I don't think so. In firefox looks as it is zoomed 120%. In Safari, Chrome looks the same - 100%. In all browsers it is 100%, I can't find why firefox looks as if it is zoomed 120%

Answer (score 0):

Please don't mind but there may be issue with your firefox. Please press Ctrl+0 key to reset browser zooming. I've find many friends who made this silly mistake and keep searching for solution in css.

If it's not the case then check zoom css, if it is defined else reset it to 1 or 100%.

Comment: It's 100%, not my mistake. In normalize.css I have: ```html {
    font-family: sans-serif; /* 1 */
    -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; /* 2 */
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; /* 2 */
}``` I compare site in firefox, safari and chrome and it is 100% zoom everywhere. Only in firefox it looks as if it is 120%

Comment: Oh, in my display settings I had "Medium - 125%". My resolution is:1920x1080. I changed to "Smaller-100%" and they look both in one way. But when it is "Medium-125% - why only firefox is zoomed, but not chrome, safari?

Comment: Try to add this css for html
-moz-text-size-adjust: 100%;