# Safari is not showing the top 1 pixel of the webpage?

Tags: html, css, safari

With the following HTML:

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
  <style>
    body {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
    div {
      border: 1px solid yellow;
      height: 100px;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div></div>
</body>
</html>
```

This page is hosted on https://vrot.nl/test.html.

If you open this in Safari, the top border of the `div` is not shown. You have to scroll the page down to see the top border, it's inside the "rubber band effect" area so to speak.

No other browsers have this problem it seems. What is causing this, and how can I work around this so that all browsers look the same?

Comment: Perhaps you need more resetting? 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34369778/using-reset-css-looks-different-in-different-browsers

Comment: Yeah that is the question, isn't it? What CSS property would fix this? Also a browser not showing the top 1 pixel shouldn't need a CSS reset.

Comment: And no, adding the standard HTML5 Reset Stylesheet didn't solve it.

Comment: I'm able to see the top border without modifying any code!

Comment: In Safari 16.3?

Comment: On Safari 16.1, I can see the above line.

Comment: Is the top border completely offscreen, or is it like half a pixel gets cut off?

Comment: Can confirm that in Safari 15.6.1 on a MacBook Pro Retina screen, half of the top border is cut off. `html { maring-top: 1px }` fixes the issue, but also leaves a gap in other browsers, so I'm not sure that would be a viable solution. It looks like this is just a glitch in Safari, I'm not sure there is a non hacky cross browser solution.

Comment: @sideshowbarker why did you delete the answer that Nat posted. It is essentially on the right track.

Comment: It seems related to Dark Mode: I don't see the top 1 pixel in Dark Mode, but I do see it when I change macOS to be in Light Mode, although the top 1 pixel is slightly darker. It seems like a Safari bug for sure.

Comment: Suggestion. You can use `box-shadow` instead of `border` like this: `-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 1px rgba(255,255,0,1);
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 1px rgba(255,255,0,1);
box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 1px rgba(255,255,0,1);`

Comment: The point is not the border vs box-shadow. The point is that the top 1 pixel of the page is not visible. The border is just to visualize that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to only affect Safari, and only in Dark Mode. So, this bit of CSS fixes the issue:

```css
@supports (-webkit-hyphens:none) {
  @media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {
    body {
      padding-top: 1px;
    }
  }
}
```

It's crazy that this is necessary though. I've submitted a bug report to Apple (FB12075967).